# How to Get friend list of facebook login user using FacebookSDK v3.21

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-invite

i try following code to get list of friend, but i am getting those friend who using app, i need to get full list of friend. code is given below.

```
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          NSLog(@"My Friend listed : is %@",result);
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

Comment: I am afraid that from Facebook Graph API 2.0, you CAN NOT fetch all your friends by using /me/friends. I don't know why Facebook do this update. So, many many apps will be die. :(

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API call now only returns friends who have used the app. so, you can't fetch your whole friend list, only friends who are also using the app.

Check this link for more info

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends

Comment: ok. i need to invite friend those not install app. so what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

With Facebook SDK 3.0 you can do this:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                  NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you got, `/me/friends` returns friends who are using the app.

From the Facebook doc references

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0

use `@"/me/invitable_friends"` instead of  `@"/me/friends"`

> UPDATED

As of **`April 30th'2014`**, apps can only get the list of friends who are also using the app, and you have to request the `user_friends` permission as you are getting now. For those users who have never logged in to your app before **`April 30th'2014`** will get an `app_scoped_id` instead of their real facebook id.

Comment: my app is in the category of bussiness app, not the game so i can't use  : /me/invitable_friends.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Request dialog and `invitable_friends` are out of the question, as you are talking about an iOS App (not a Game on Canvas). So according to the docs, this is the best option: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/#message-dialog